# Data Field Value Equivalents

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, linq, data-migration

I couldn't find the answer to this one, perhaps for lack of knowing what search terms to even use.

I'm in the process of cleaning up a C#-based spaghetti-code data migration tool. As per advice from a previous question, I'm doing this now using Entity Framework to describe nice "neat" relationships between the two systems.

One part that I just can't get my head around is the "right way" to translate equivalent field values. For example:

**Old-DB (City)** = "NY" **New-DB (City)** = "New York"

**Old-DB (Department)** = "Accounts" **New-DB (Department)** = "Accounting"

I'm sure that the only way to do this would be with some kind of "static" resource to lookup/cross-reference the field values.
I've had ideas like:

- DataTables (CityTable, AccountTable etc.) List FieldPairs
- List item {OldValue="NY", NewValue="New York"} etc.
- Worse still - LookupDictionary.txt

But these feel just wrong. And I'm trying to do this thing "properly". Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks kindly

Comment: If you want your relationships to be evaluated on the database server, you will need to create a mapping table on the server to join the fields. That probably isn't a bad idea in any case to centralize the location of the mapping data.

Answer (score 0):

What about a Dictionary ?

```
            Dictionary<string, string> replaceCityValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            replaceCityValues.Add("NY", "New York");
            replaceCityValues.Add("LA", "Los Angeles");

            var toReplace = replaceCityValues.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == "NY");
            if(toReplace != null)
```

If you have 'static' values for the target replace you could also use an enum.

On the other hand, a List is more easy to serialize and provide someone the xml file to extend for new replace values...